# Conditionally showing a list in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to be able to be able to achieve something like this in Excel:

Let's say on cell B10:

=IF(A1=3;2;Show a list of values (based on a defined list name or range) using a dropdown)

In other words, if the value of A1=3, I just want to display a value, like the number 2; otherwise, show a pre-defined list.

I've searched a lot, but I haven't been able to find an answer to this question.

I am using Office 2016 for Mac.

Comment: you may need VBA for this. `Worksheet_Change` event may be handy.

Comment: What is the predefined list? Is there more than one list?  If you want to use a drop down you'll need to use data validation.